# Edsim51 Always Invalid Label Error

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, edsim51

I'm using [EDSIM51](http://www.edsim51.com/) on MacOS. But I'm always getting **Invalid Label - **** is keyword** errors. Read documentation (*User's Guide* and *Examples* pages) but still no idea where I'm making mistake. I've downloaded example codes from Edsim's website, but it's giving same error for their official examples.

For example,
This is an LCD example which taken from their website:

```
; put data in RAM
    MOV 30H, #'A'
    MOV 31H, #'B'
    MOV 32H, #'C'
    MOV 33H, #0 ; end of data marker


; initialise the display
; see instruction set for details


    CLR P1.3        ; clear RS - indicates that instructions are being sent to the module

; function set  
    CLR P1.7        ; |
    CLR P1.6        ; |
    SETB P1.5       ; |
    CLR P1.4        ; | high nibble set

    SETB P1.2       ; |
    CLR P1.2        ; | negative edge on E

    CALL delay      ; wait for BF to clear  
                    ; function set sent for first time - tells module to go into 4-bit mode
; Why is function set high nibble sent twice? See 4-bit operation on pages 39 and 42 of HD44780.pdf.

    SETB P1.2       ; |
    CLR P1.2        ; | negative edge on E
                    ; same function set high nibble sent a second time

    SETB P1.7       ; low nibble set (only P1.7 needed to be changed)

    SETB P1.2       ; |
    CLR P1.2        ; | negative edge on E
                ; function set low nibble sent
    CALL delay      ; wait for BF to clear


; entry mode set
; set to increment with no shift
    CLR P1.7        ; |
    CLR P1.6        ; |
    CLR P1.5        ; |
    CLR P1.4        ; | high nibble set

    SETB P1.2       ; |
    CLR P1.2        ; | negative edge on E

    SETB P1.6       ; |
    SETB P1.5       ; |low nibble set

    SETB P1.2       ; |
    CLR P1.2        ; | negative edge on E

    CALL delay      ; wait for BF to clear


; display on/off control
; the display is turned on, the cursor is turned on and blinking is turned on
    CLR P1.7        ; |
    CLR P1.6        ; |
    CLR P1.5        ; |
    CLR P1.4        ; | high nibble set

    SETB P1.2       ; |
    CLR P1.2        ; | negative edge on E

    SETB P1.7       ; |
    SETB P1.6       ; |
    SETB P1.5       ; |
    SETB P1.4       ; | low nibble set

    SETB P1.2       ; |
    CLR P1.2        ; | negative edge on E

    CALL delay      ; wait for BF to clear


; send data
    SETB P1.3       ; clear RS - indicates that data is being sent to module
    MOV R1, #30H    ; data to be sent to LCD is stored in 8051 RAM, starting at location 30H
loop:
    MOV A, @R1      ; move data pointed to by R1 to A
    JZ finish       ; if A is 0, then end of data has been reached - jump out of loop
    CALL sendCharacter  ; send data in A to LCD module
    INC R1          ; point to next piece of data
    JMP loop        ; repeat

finish:
    JMP $


sendCharacter:
    MOV C, ACC.7        ; |
    MOV P1.7, C         ; |
    MOV C, ACC.6        ; |
    MOV P1.6, C         ; |
    MOV C, ACC.5        ; |
    MOV P1.5, C         ; |
    MOV C, ACC.4        ; |
    MOV P1.4, C         ; | high nibble set

    SETB P1.2           ; |
    CLR P1.2            ; | negative edge on E

    MOV C, ACC.3        ; |
    MOV P1.7, C         ; |
    MOV C, ACC.2        ; |
    MOV P1.6, C         ; |
    MOV C, ACC.1        ; |
    MOV P1.5, C         ; |
    MOV C, ACC.0        ; |
    MOV P1.4, C         ; | low nibble set

    SETB P1.2           ; |
    CLR P1.2            ; | negative edge on E

    CALL delay          ; wait for BF to clear

delay:
    MOV R0, #50
    DJNZ R0, $
    RET
```

**AND ERROR : ** Invalid Label - FİNİSH is keyword

Can you please tell me what is I'm missing?

Comment: P.S. I've check other SE websites especially about electronics and electrics (like electronics.stackexchange.com) but there is no question about EDSIM . But there are some edsim questions on SO (https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=edsim+stackoverflow) , so I decided to ask this question in here.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, must be faulty install of edsim, try to re-install.

Comment: @ShellFish same error..

Comment: Maybe we should take a closer look at the error and assume `finish` is a reserved keyword. Try to change the label to another one like `finishfunction`. Of course you should replace references to `finish` to `finishfunction` as well.